# camera app that launches the native camera and then displays the image on the main page

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, camera, uiimageview

i am a beginner in android and have been trying to understand its basic concepts. i tried making an application with one button and an imageview. the button launched the camera and once you've taken the pic and saved it, it should show it in the image view. however, it is not doing so, i have tried searching for the code online and its more or less exactly the same. any help you could provide will be much appreciated!
thanks!
Heres my code:

```
package com.example.camapp;

import java.net.URI;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.provider.MediaStore;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button btn;
ImageView imgview;
Bitmap b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        imgview=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent n=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(n, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode , intent);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            b = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("intent");
    //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value Of B : " + intent.getData(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //      URI u=URI.create(intent.getData().toString());
            imgview.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Else", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a uses feature in your manifest

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Change obtaining image to :

```
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Alternatively, write more details which part does not work.